# Error in Spring MVC - displaying a form with Modal attribute having a select item

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

This is in continuation with my previous question : [Spring MVC with Hibernate Data Saving Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447335/spring-mvc-with-hibernate-data-saving-error).

The previous error was resolved based on the answer there. Now I want to show the the Saved value back in the form.

```
    @RequestMapping("manage")
public String manage(@ModelAttribute Automotive automotive,
        BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

    List<Company> companies = companyService.listAllCompanies();
    model.addAttribute("companies", companies);

    automotiveService.addAutomotive(automotive);
    return "automotive/index";
}
```

And my view is

```
<form:form action="/Automotive/manage" modelAttribute="automotive">
    <form:hidden path="id" />
    Name : <form:input path="name" />
    Description : <form:input path="description" />
    Type : <form:input path="type" />
    Company : <form:select path="company" items="${companies}"
        itemLabel="name" itemValue="id" title="Company"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form:form>
```

I'm able to save the data properly but on returning it shows an error is thrown:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session


root cause: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:149)
org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:195)
org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
biz.canisrigel.automirror.model.Company_$$_javassist_0.toString(Company_$$_javassist_0.java)
org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.nullSafeToString(ObjectUtils.java:610)
```

**UPDATE**

On using Kevin's suggestion of OpenSessioninViewFilter I get the error of No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined since I'm using session factory interface.

Comment: The explanation is in the javadoc of the exception. And on gazillions of questions here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/LazyInitializationException.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempting to access lazy loaded entities in your view which does not have a Hibernate session, therefore it cannot make calls to the database.

Spring provides an `OpenSessionInViewFilter` that extends the `Session` to the view.  It is configured by adding the following to your web.xml:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: @Kevin-bowersox I use session factory interface. so on using the above code I get an error message: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined

Answer (score 0):

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException
```

This is related to `Hibernate` Issue.

By thi sexception it is telling like You have fetched `Parent` object from DB which holds `Child` Object. And You are trying to Access child Object from Parent in Controller may cause the problem.

```
Check Parent entity fetch Lazy false
```

Answer (score 0):

To be used if you're using sessionfactory interface

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```